# Dart component progress bar only updating at the end of loop

Tags: user-interface, dart, angular-dart

I'm developing an app in angular dart and trying to animate a progress bar which shows progress of a file upload. I'm simply parsing the JSON from the file, and sending them off to a service with a `_service.create(....)` method.

I've put all of this code in an `async` method which is called when my submit button is clicked:

```
void uploadFile() async {

  submitButton.attributes.addAll({ 'disabled': '' });
  progress.value = 0;

  FileList files = input.files;

  if (files.isEmpty) {
    _handleError("No file selected");
    //handle error, probably a banner
    return;
  }

  File file = files.item(0);

  FileReader reader = new FileReader();
  //reader.result
  reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) async {


    Map map = json.decode(reader.result);

    var combinations = map['combinations'];

    progress.max = combinations.length;

    int loopCount = 0;

    combinations.forEach((e) async {
      await _service.create(VJCombination.fromJSON(e)).then((_) {
        combinationCount++;
        progress.value++;

        loopCount++;

        if (loopCount == combinations.length) {
          submitButton.attributes.remove('disabled');
        }
      });

    });

    isLoadSuccessful = true;

  });

  reader.onError.listen((evt) => print(evt));

  reader.readAsText(file);

  progress.value = 10;

}
```

I'm getting the `progress` and the `submitButton` elements with the `@ViewChild` annotations:

```
@ViewChild('progress')
ProgressElement progress;

@ViewChild('submit')
ButtonElement submitButton;
```

The code works. The progress bar starts off empty, and after the file is read and the service gets the data, the progress bar is full.

My issue is that the UI is only updated after all of the combinations have been sent to the `_service`. So it seemingly goes from empty to full in one frame.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
 combinations.forEach((e) async {
```

does not make sense, because `forEach` does not care about the returned `Future`

Rather use

```
 for(var e in combinations) {
```

Not sure if this fixes your problem, but such code definitely needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have since changed the `forEach` to a `for` loop. It doesn't fix my issue though :(

Comment: I think you need to inject `ChangeDetectorRef cdRef` to your component and call `cdRef.markForCheck();` before the end of the for loop: `for(...) { ... ; cdRef.markForCheck(); }`

Comment: Still no luck, it doesn't seem to have any effect on the refreshing.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: I've come across this article: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/note/effective/change-detection and I think it's just the amount of work being done when the button is clicked - it's quite an expensive operation. So I think i'll have to find a better way to call the function.